# Call async function in angular 7 interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create an interceptor which should call a function to refresh the session when a 401 error is returned. This is what I have so far but it won't build and I can't work out how to do this:

```
intercept(
request: HttpRequest<any>,
next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
request = request.clone({
  withCredentials: true
});
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (error.status === 401) {
      return this.userAPI
        .refreshSession(this.authService.getRefreshToken())
        .then(res => {
          this.authService.setAuthenticated(false);
          return next.handle(request);
        });
    } else {
      this.authService.setAuthenticated(false);
    }
  })
 );
}
```

VS Code reports:

```
Type 'Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any> | Observable<HttpEvent<any>>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catchError` must return an observable. Try below or something similar:

```
intercept(
request: HttpRequest<any>,
next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
request = request.clone({
  withCredentials: true
});
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (error.status === 401) {
      return this.userAPI
        .refreshSession(this.authService.getRefreshToken())
        .then(res => {
          this.authService.setAuthenticated(false);
          return next.handle(request);
        });
    } else {
      this.authService.setAuthenticated(false);
      // Add this
      return next.handle(request);
    }
  })
 );
}
```